# Is it possible to pick up secondary weapons in COD?

Tags: call-of-duty-series

In COD, is it possible to pick up secondary weapons from defeated opponents, or can I only swap out my primary weapon? I never took much notice of this before, but after having a break from COD and recently playing again this has become quite obvious to me.

In many other games that I have played it is possible to replace any weapon being carried, but in COD I cannot seem to work out how to do this for secondary weapons. This would be especially useful for dual wielding since ammunition is spent at a much faster rate.

Can this be done?

Comment: Which Call of Duty specifically are you playing? The tag you used is for the original game

Comment: I assume this works similarly in the series, therefore any game. I may have used the incorrect tag though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, in fact, replace your secondary weapon. This is a tactic me and my friends have used since call of duty 2, and atleast up to modern warfare 2.

Comment: So in order to pick up an enemy's secondary weapon they would need to die with their secondary drawn? If they had the dual wield/akimbo attachment that would mean picking up 2 secondaries right?